# Google Maps Android V2 - Blank Screen When Debug

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a strange problem.

I try to use standard Google Maps V2 sample from an Android SDK. But I import it to Android Studio.

I made Google API key for this sample app and I signed the app.

Strange is that when I try to debug the app on my device from Android Studio - then I get a Blank Screen instead the map. But when I make a signed apk and then install it on my device manually - it's all right, I can see the map.

What's wrong with the debug mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your debug.keystore file's SHA1 to your google api console. Further info:

[Debug mode sign](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode)